# How to show the complete title of an app?

Tags: home-screen, trebuchet

Some apps with a longer title show up on the launcher screen (trebuchet) with a shortened title. E.g. an application with the title "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" will be titled "abcdefghi..". 
The same applies to videos linked with a shortcut to the screeen (I used the app "media shortcut" for this).

Is there a way to show the whole title before opening the app or the video? I have a lot of videos that I would like to distinguish before opening them.

Comment: That's the limitation of Home/Launcher app. Try different.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is not way to do this.

I believe that *some* launchers *may* wrap titles, but I can't think of any that do.

As per dymutaos' comment:

> ADW wraps the titles of apps. They wrap it to a second line, and they make the second line smaller in order to fit within a certain space. Though if the name is really long and doesn't fit within 2 lines, it still gets truncated.

Comment: ADW wraps the titles of apps. They wrap it to a second line, and they make the second line smaller in order to fit within a certain space. Though if the name is really long and doesn't fit within 2 lines, it still gets truncated.